# opencart $setting variable in module controller function index($setting) is empty

Tags: opencart

when create module, i want use $setting array

```
<?php
class ControllerModuleMymodule extends Controller {
  protected function index($setting) {
...
```

but it is empty. I know it get from admin controller, but how to fill it?

Comment: Create some options on your module's admin page. Look at another module for examples.

Answer (score 0):

(1.5.X answer)

`$setting` is automatically filled by the `mymodule_module` values. You can see an example of this if you look at some of the pre-made modules that come with OC. For example, the account module. You'll see that you can add multiple modules and position them. The settings for each one is an array such as `account_module[0]['layout_id']` and `account_module[0]['position']`. OpenCart loads the `account_module` setting and unserializes the settings array, then passes each one to the controller in turn via a for loop. You can see this if you view the source of one of the positions a module can be, such as the `/catalog/controller/common/column_left.php` file.

```
    $extensions = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('module');      

    foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
        // Loads the settings for all of this extensions modules and unserializes (this is done behind the scenes of the get() method)
        $modules = $this->config->get($extension['code'] . '_module');

        if ($modules) {
            // Loop for each module to be rendered (checking it's valid for this particular position)
            foreach ($modules as $module) {
                if ($module['layout_id'] == $layout_id && $module['position'] == 'column_left' && $module['status']) {
                    $module_data[] = array(
                        'code'       => $extension['code'],
                        'setting'    => $module, // This data is passed to your controller in subsequent code
                        'sort_order' => $module['sort_order']
                    );              
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Jay, I mean opencart 2.0.0 Look for example catalog/module/carousel.php: <?php
class ControllerModuleCarousel extends Controller {
 public function index($setting) { and catalog/module/category.php: <?php
class ControllerModuleCategory extends Controller {
 public function index() { why for carousel $setting is set, but for category $setting is empty?

Comment: hm.. for me this worked: use, for example, not $setting['category_status'], but $this->config->get('category_status'). Cant find out how to fill $setting with.

Comment: `$setting` does not include the general config data in 2.0, it's the position of the module from the layout section, which has been moved to it's own placement under `SYSTEM > DESIGN > LAYOUT` where you can assign modules